# BootUp Receiver(ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) not receiving in Android N

Tags: android

I used the following codes

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<receiver
            android:name=".XXX.BootupReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

public class BootupReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {

            Intent pushIntent = new Intent(context, XXXservice.class);
            context.startService(pushIntent);

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is after installing the application and on rebooting, receiver is not triggering. But after launching the app once, then rebooting the receiver is working fine. Why this happening?

Answer (score 0):

This happen because of security feature I searched around the web and found a solution.

If your device is Xiaomi devices,then you just have to add your app to Autostart list, to do so, follow these simple steps given below:
 Open Security app on your phone.Tap on Permissions, it'll show you two options: Autostart and Permissions.Tap on Autostart, it'll show you list of apps with on or off toggle buttons.Turn on toggle of your app, you're done!
Now, reboot your phone, you'll see a Toast message I am Running

Comment: Not Xiami. the issue is in all devices from Android 3+